# Simple way to keep files updated from remote server using java?

Tags: java

I was hoping to use Java to access a remote server, and access the files and keep my files updated, or update the files on the server.

Is there a simple way to access a remote server using the username@host and password, which would allow me to upload and download files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to access files via ssh remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper tool for the job: [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Answer (score 0):

If you like to connect to a machine while opening a ssh connection , 
to run OS command you can use trilead.
This is an example to a method that will open a connection.

```
    public static Connection newConnectionNoPassword(String host, String username, File privateKey) {
    Connection newConn = new Connection(host);
    try {
        newConn.connect(); // Ignoring ConnectionInfo returned value.
        //If the authentication was successful the authenticated connection will be returend
        if ( newConn.authenticateWithPublicKey(username, privateKey, null)){
            return newConn;
        }else{
            newConn.close();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        newConn.close();
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you use maven you can get it by adding the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.trilead</groupId>
        <artifactId>trilead-ssh2</artifactId>
        <version>build213-svnkit-1.3-patch</version>
    </dependency>
```

In order to upload\download files from\to a server you can use trilead SCPClient.
Here is an example of downloading files from a remote server to a local folder:

```
    public void downloadFiles(String[] remoteFiles, String localDir) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    checkNotEmpty(localDir);
    checkNotEmpty(remoteFiles);

    File dir = new File(localDir);
    if (!dir.exists() || !dir.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to create local directory : " + localDir);
    }

    SCPClient scp = new SCPClient(this.conn);
    try {
        scp.get(remoteFiles, localDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to copy remote files to local folder", e);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..